# Thermal printer printing AT#PORTCFG?

Tags: usb, printing

I have a thermal printer plugged on the machine by USB-to-Serial:

```
[422487.983278] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[422489.500951] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=1c8a, idProduct=3011
[422489.500957] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[422489.500961] usb 1-7: Product: USB To Serial Interface
[422489.500964] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: SWEDA
[422489.500967] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: 0000000000022
[422489.503978] cdc_acm 1-7:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

It ocasionally prints

```
AT#PORTCFG?
```

on the thermal paper.

I guess something is sending commands to the port.

Any ideas on how to avoid it?

Ubuntu 18.04.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue and found a solution using brute force:

```
# grep -r PORTCFG
Binary file lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ModemManager/libmm-plugin-telit.so matches
Binary file lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ModemManager/libmm-plugin-dell.so matches
```

So the answer is:

```
# systemctl stop ModemManager.service
```

And optionally:

```
# systemctl disable ModemManager.service
```